# Database Encoding - German Caracteres

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, codificação-de-caracteres

Deparo-me com uma situação estranha, quando tento inserir German caracteres(ä,ä) na base de dados eles são inseridos da seguinte forma:

```
"Ã¼Ã¼Ã¼ "
```

O campo está defino como `utf8_general_ci`

Se inserir os dados numa query diretamente na base dados, esta aceita estes caracteres especiais, se inserir atraves de uma query em php estes ficam da forma referida anteriormente.

Estou a usar a class `PDO` para inserir dados.

Qual pode ser a causa desse problema?

Answer (score 2):

Os dados armazenados são codificados em UTF-8 (ü para um "O" é típico para UTF-8), mas não é exibido como UTF-8, mas sim como ISO-8859-1 ou similares.

Certifique-se de que você use a mesma codificação em todos os lugares:

Use

```
mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Para definir a codificação para UTF-8
  Certifique-se de que a codificação do banco de dados é UTF-8 (use HeidiSQL etc. para verificar)